# Cannot make post request, formData is empty after append

Tags: javascript, form-data

I'm trying to collect data from files, `formData` is empty after `append`.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
for (let i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
  formData.append('file', files[i]);
}
```

[image: format files, images]

Comment: How do you check if the date is empty?

Comment: const formData = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  formData.push('file', files[i]);
}                                                                                                                                               you try use push() method  to append the files to the FormData object maybe

Comment: @EminAbdullayev formData.push is not a function

Comment: @ТарасГуледза you can't push data to formData.
Only append.

Are you sure that the formdata is empty? The code is normal, maybe you are not checking correctly.

(and in general it is better to rename the constant from formdata to something else)

Comment: just look using the following code, add @ts-ignore for a while if the project is with typescript

console.log([...formData])

Comment: This post needs more context and a complete [mcve].